# Are there any third party profiling tool for azure db

Tags: azure-sql-database

Are there any third party profiling tool for azure db?
I am looking for free tools which can help me to profiling azure db in SSMS.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of specific 3rd party tools for Azure SQL Database.  In part, because it's a PaaS service, some of our prior on-premise tools such as SSMS and SQL profiler won't work (as you don't have admin access - paraphrasing here).

One way to make progress here could be with the new query store that's designed to help understand what's going on query-wise.  http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/06/08/query-store-a-flight-data-recorder-for-your-database/